# How to get JTable size after data change occurs

Tags: java, image, jtable, graphics2d

I've been working on a project to pull data from an API and put it in a JTable. When the JTable is populated with data I'd like for it to save an image of everything within the table, including the headers.

The problem is the data seems to only be saved one time. If I manipulate the table (I.E: use a different JComponent to remove rows) and try saving the image again it gives an error because the height/width cannot be set to 0.

Here is [some of] my code for adding data into the table:

```
    missionTable = new JTable(info, headers);
    for (int i = 0; i < missionTable.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        missionTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(new RarityRenderer());
    }
    int maxSize = 0;
    JTextArea label = null;
    // Resize rows to fit table values
    for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
        maxSize = 0;
        if (info[i] != null && info[i][2] != null && info[i][3] != null) {
            label = new JTextArea(info[i][2]);
            label.setBounds(0, 0, 95, 20);
            if (label.getPreferredSize().height > maxSize)
                maxSize = label.getPreferredSize().height;
            label = new JTextArea(info[i][3]);
            label.setBounds(0, 0, 320, 20);
            label.setLineWrap(true);
            label.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            if (label.getPreferredSize().height > maxSize)
                maxSize = label.getPreferredSize().height;
        }
        if (maxSize > 0)
            missionTable.setRowHeight(i, maxSize > 40 ? 52 : 40);
    }
    label = null;
    missionScrollPane.setViewportView(missionTable);
    System.out.println("H:" + missionTable.getHeight() + " W:" + missionTable.getWidth());
    saveTable(missionTable, "./test.jpg");// Line 904 from stacktrace
```

And here is the saveTable(JTable, String) method:

```
public void saveTable(JTable table, String filename) {
    try {

        int ww = Math.max(table.getWidth(), table.getTableHeader().getWidth());
        int hh = table.getHeight() + table.getTableHeader().getHeight();
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(ww, hh, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);// Line 980 from stacktrace
        Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();
        table.getTableHeader().paint(g2);
        g2.translate(0, table.getTableHeader().getHeight());
        table.paint(g2);
        g2.dispose();

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(out);
        encoder.encode(bi);
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Along with the output + stacktrace:

```
H:0 W:0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (0) and height (0) cannot be <= 0
    at java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at stuff.game.ux.StormUI.saveComponentAsJPEG(StormUI.java:980)
    at stuff.game.ux.StormUI.refreshCurrentTable(StormUI.java:904)
    at stuff.game.ux.StormUI.changeFilter(StormUI.java:720)
    at stuff.game.ux.StormUI$9.mouseClicked(StormUI.java:425)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I've honestly run out of things to try, setting the height/width manually only creates a solid black image.

Comment: Table-image is not loaded therefore when you call table.getHeight() and set it as image height it returns -1. You have 3-4 ways of implementing this to work, one of it would be to get ww, hh and bi initalization code away try loop

Comment: What do you mean Table-image is not loaded? As in it's not on the view port so it can't construct the image? I'm just not understanding why it works the first time but not if I filter the data.

Comment: It takes some time for an image to load/scale, therefore it throws -1 for w and -1 for h if it is not loaded/scaled fully. Just put an if loop to check if that name exists and if exists delete it. before going with try loop in your saveTable.

Comment: First time it works like a charm, but all other times it requires load factor to load a dead-but-assigned image into processing.

Comment: That fixes it! I thought it was a problem similar to this so I used `Thread.sleep(5000);` not thinking about the fact this would stop the thread that's loading the image.

Comment: Glad it helped! :-)